# SQL Server query, most frequent in hour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select, group-by

I have a table where I insert page loads. The interesting fields are entrytime and country.

How do I query, so that I can get the most frequent country by hour. The result set should look like this (Hour, Country):

- 01 - USA
- 02 - Singapore
- 03 - India
- 04 - Denmark

... and so on.

I was getting started with something like

```
select DatePart(hour, entrytime) AS h, country from rpageload group by DatePart(hour, entrytime), country
```

but I think I am going in the wrong direction. ORDER BY and COUNT(*) needs to fit in somewhere :)

-- EDITED / ADDED --

I have found out that this sort-of gives me the right results. But I obviously also get many result sets, and not just one, like I'd like.

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 0
WHILE (@count < 24)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @count AS hr, COUNT(*) AS nbr, country FROM rpageload WHERE DATEPART(hour, entrytime) = @count GROUP BY country ORDER BY nbr DESC
    SET @count = (@count + 1)
END
```

Just to clarify: The day or date doesn't matter. The purpose is to show which country is most frequent in the different hours of the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there!

```
SELECT DatePart(hour, entrytime) AS h, country
FROM rpageload 
GROUP BY DatePart(hour, entrytime), country
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

However, this will combine entries from every single day per hour
So between 1-2pm yesterday will be counted together with 1-2pm today

If this is undesired, you need to filter out other days in a WHERE clause.
Alternatively, group by days on top of the hours

Edit:
Actually, I didn't read the question properly.

```
SELECT DatePart(hour, entrytime) AS h, country
FROM rpageload rp1
GROUP BY DatePart(hour, entrytime), country
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
 (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
  FROM rpageload rp2
  WHERE DatePart(rp2.hour, rp2.entrytime) = DatePart(rp1.hour, rp1.entrytime)
  GROUP BY DatePart(hour, entrytime), country
 )
ORDER BY h
```

What should happen when two or more countries have the same count and it's the maximum for that hour?

Alternatively,

```
WITH RPL1 AS
(
  SELECT DatePart(hour, entrytime) AS h, country, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM rpageload rp1
  GROUP BY DatePart(hour, entrytime), country
),
RPL2 AS
(
  SELECT h, MAX(cnt) as maxcnt
  FROM RPL1
  GROUP BY h
)
SELECT RPL1.h, country
FROM RPL1
JOIN RPL2 ON RPL1.h = RPL2.h AND RPL1.cnt = RPL2.maxcnt
```

The last two queries will return all rows matching the same maximum frequency. SO, the same hour may appear more than once in the resultset.

If you want to filter those out, look at [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
WITH RPL1 AS
(
  SELECT DatePart(hour, entrytime) AS h, country, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM rpageload rp1
  GROUP BY DatePart(hour, entrytime), country
),
RPL2 AS
(
  SELECT h, MAX(cnt) as maxcnt
  FROM RPL1
  GROUP BY h
),
DUPES AS
(
  SELECT RPL1.h, country, cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RPL1.h ORDER BY country) AS rn
  FROM RPL1
  JOIN RPL2 ON RPL1.h = RPL2.h AND RPL1.cnt = RPL2.maxcnt
)
SELECT h, country, cnt
FROM DUPES
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: But this result set gives me several columns with the same "h" (hour)

Comment: If two countries have the same number and it's max, just return either one :) I think that would be a rare coincidence

Comment: That last one is brilliant. (The other has syntax errors near GROUP). I think we have a winner

Comment: I've just edited the other query. I mixed up the order of WHERE and GROUP BY. Should be OK now.

Comment: Msg 4112, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
The ranking function "ROW_NUMBER" must have an ORDER BY clause.

By The Way, I'd also like the actual number (hour, country, how many) if possible :)

Comment: I am using the "third" one and just added in SELECT ... cnt to get the numbers, it's fine. I remove the extra/double hours in the app code. Thanks for a great help

Comment: Added ORDER BY and the count to the last query

Comment: Very good, it works excellent. Thanks again. (p.s. there is a comma at the end of line 3 which doesn't belong)